# how to convert varchar to number in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

My query is

```
select num from (
select substr('2*3*4',2) num  from dual)
```

I am getting '2*3*4' as result after executing but my result should be 24.Can any one please help me in converting it to number.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`TO_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140) function to convert char/varchar to a number.

You can do the following:

```
select TO_NUMBER('2')*TO_NUMBER('3')*TO_NUMBER('4') from dual;
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/15879).